# Função para pegar uma linha de uma tabela do Excel e fatiar

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

É possível pegar uma linha da tabela e dividir em quantos pedaços quiser?

Eu consigo pegar célula por célula da tabela usando uma abordagem que aprendi aqui no fórum em uma pergunta já respondida, mas acho que estou abrindo o mesmo arquivo 2.000 vezes.

É possível, senhores?

Aqui está a implementação que uso hoje:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('MONITORA.xlsm')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('PREÇO')
preço = worksheet.cell(0, 1)
preço_dois = worksheet.cell(0, 2)
```

Comment: A biblioteca utilizada foi a `xlrd`? Seria interessante incluir na pergunta e na resposta para ajudar quem vier aqui pesquisar posteriormente.

Comment: Eu ia colocar, mas precisava ter uma pontuação maior

Answer (score 2):

Eu consegui fazer usando esse código

```
excel_sheet = xlrd.open_workbook('MONITORA.xlsm')
sheet1 = excel_sheet.sheet_by_name('PREÇO')
row = sheet1.row(0)  # 1st row

for i in range(0, sheet1.nrows):
    row = sheet1.row_slice(i)
    Gname = row[0].value
    Fname = row[1].value
    Lname = row[2].value

    print (Gname)
    print (Fname)
    print (Lname)
```